# Wordpress twenty twelve adding extra margin to images

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have added these three pictures to a WP site. Code is:

```
<style> 
    #frontContainer { 
        max-width: 1200px; 
    }

    #frontContainer ul { 
        list-style: none;
    }

    #frontContainer li { 
        height: 599px; 
        width: 376px; 
        float: left; 
        margin-right: 5px;    
        border: 2px solid black;  
        opacity: 1; 
    }

    #frontContainer img { 
        height: 100%; 
        width: 100%;  

    } 

    #frontContainer li:hover{ 
        border: 2px solid #47B957; 
        opacity: .5;
     }

 </style>

 <div id='frontContainer'>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=975'><img src='http://i59.tinypic.com/2gt6fsp.jpg'/></a></li>
            <li><a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/rapid-worker/'><img src='http://i61.tinypic.com/34pifd2.jpg'/></a></li>
            <li><a href='http://pacificexpress.com.au/?p=971'><img src='http://i58.tinypic.com/348ohhg.jpg'/></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

this works when testing ( i.e. the three images sit in a row with 5px margin in-between each image) however once I add this to the website (wordpress platform running twenty-twelve theme) it seems to increase the margin.

I cannot seem to change this ... anyone able to help with this ?

the site is www.pacificexpress.com.au

cheers

James M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra margins are coming from a left margin specified in a `.entry-content li` selector, and to get rid of that you just need to override the margin on the `<li>`s with 0px.

```
#frontContainer li {
    height: 599px;
    width: 376px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0px;  /*or whatever other value you want*/
    border: 2px solid black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```